# Powershell - CSV Export formatting

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I am trying to get list of AD groups a user is part of and I have a script that works. But I need to show it in a different manner. Currently the script shows a record in one line with username and then multiple group names in the next cell delimited by a semi-colon.

I would like it in a way that all groups are in each seperate row and the username gets repeated.

Example:

DavidChow - Server Admin Group

DavidChow - Desktop Admin Group

DavidChow - Azure Admin Group

NinaChow - Desktop User Group

This is my script:

```
        $UnameList= Import-Csv C:\temp\users_full_list.csv
ForEach ($username in $UnameList){
$groups=Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $username.Identity | select -expand name
$data = [PSCustomObject]@{
          samaccountname = $username.Identity
          count = $groups.count
          memberOf = ($groups -join ';')}
 Write-Output $data  | Export-Csv C:\Temp\users_full_list_memberships.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Append
         }
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "data" object for *each* group of each user, and then export all to CSV at the end:

```bsh
Import-Csv C:\temp\users_full_list.csv | foreach {
    $identity = $_.Identity
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $identity | foreach {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
              SamAccountName = $identity
              GroupName = $_.Name
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\Temp\users_full_list_memberships.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```